# Creating largest integer from numbers in array

Tags: java, arrays

I want to write a function for getting a largest number formed by appending numbers in int array.
`String makeLargestNo(int[] arr);`

```
static String makeLargestNo(int[] arr){
    int length = arr.length;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    TreeMap<String, String> tm = new TreeMap<String, String>();

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        int n = arr[i];

        while( n > 10){
            n = n / 10;
        }

        tm.put(String.valueOf(n), String.valueOf(arr[i]));                      
    }

    ArrayList<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>(tm.keySet());

    for(int i = keys.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--){          
        sb.append(tm.get(keys.get(i)));
    }

    return sb.toString();   
}
```

But then i found out that if param array has numbers like 98 and 92 then only one of them is stored in map.

Please help

Comment: I'm not completely clear on what you are trying to do...  I think one problem is that your local variable n is being instantiated as an int.  Therefore 98 and 92, when divided by 10, both equate to a value of 9.  I might suggest using the double type, and possibly Math.Round()  but again, it depends what you are trying to do.

Comment: Maybe you want to use the array index as the map key and `n` as the map value? The keys in a `TreeMap` are unique.

Comment: Yeah, I have no clue what you are trying to do.  You appear to get the leading digit of each number, then map that digit to the number itself, then create a string which has all of the values in the map appended to each other (in sorted order according to the leading digit) _and_ not to mention (as ne1410s did) if you have two values whose leading digit is the same, then it will overwrite the previous thing.  Don't you just want `for(final int n: arr) sb.append("" + n); return sb.toString();`?

Comment: suppose my input is {12,438,67} then output should be 6743812 the largest possible number. Hope I am clear now

Comment: I think you can convert your number to an array of chars, then sort them by descending alphanumerical order, then recombine them.  Happy to suggest an implementation of this, if it sounds what you're after

Comment: yeah Jared, thats where my logic is not working i.e. in i/o array if we have two numbers with same 1st digit...

Comment: You should create a `Comparator<Integer>` class and then use it to sort the array--no need for a `TreeMap`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like maybe you're trying to do this?

```
public static String makeLargestNo(int[] arr) {
    List<String> elements = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        int n = arr[i];

        //while(n>10){
        //    n=n/10;
        //}

        elements.add(String.valueOf(n));
    }

    Collections.sort(elements);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = elements.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        sb.append(elements.get(i));
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Is that what you're trying to do?

Or, if you're wanting a number, make the method

```
public static Number makeLargestNo(int[] arr);
```

and `return new BigDecimal(sb.toString());` or something like that.

EDIT:

From your clarification in the comments, it sounds like you don't want the `while` loop at all. I've commented it out in the code above.

Also, I've changed the `List` to contain `String`s, since it looks like you want a lexicographical sort, rather than a regular numeric sort.

Comment: I don't think lexicographical sort will work either since 673 is larger than 67, but largest int is 67673

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ethan. What i can see in ur reply is that u r sorting the array elements. But thats not wat i want. If i/o array is {9,23,75} then o/p number should be 97523. Yeah C.B. got it right!

Comment: Well, I'm sorting the elements, but I'm also sorting them as Strings. So 9,23,75 wouldn't be sorted in that order, it would be sorted 23,75,9 (I think). So then appending those strings in reverse order gives you what you want. But @C.B's objection still stands -- this order isn't always best: 9,23,231 would be sorted 23,231,9, which would be concatenated as 923123. But the highest possible concatenation in that case would be 923231. So this way won't consistently give you the best result :/

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think that your first response is not so bad. 
You want an array of all the arguments `int[] arr` which start with 9 (such as 9, 90, 91, 92, ... 99, 901, 902, ..., 999), and similar for all arguments `int[] arr` which start with 8, 7, ... etc. 
Then each of these would need to be sorted for the best (999 is best, 998, ... 990 are all better than 98).
And off you go.